# AdMob for iOS error: Llibrary not found for -lGoogleAdMobAds

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, admob

I followed the steps to integrate AdMob for my iOS App, everything is ok, but i have one fatal error (so i guess something is not ok)

Here is the message:

```
Ld /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Liga_Zon_Sagres_Companion-fjlwctxjtriqrbgpjiscdoodhcgr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Liga\ Zon\ Sagres\ Companion.app/Liga\ Zon\ Sagres\ Companion normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/bertobettencourt/Desktop/LIVE RELEASES/Liga Zon Sagres (iOS)/1.30"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/bertobettencourt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Liga_Zon_Sagres_Companion-fjlwctxjtriqrbgpjiscdoodhcgr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/bertobettencourt/Desktop/LIVE\ RELEASES/Liga\ Zon\ Sagres\ (iOS)/1.30/Liga\ Zon\ Sagres\ Companion/Flurry\ iPhone\ SDK\ viPhone\ 4/Flurry-iOS-4.4.0/Flurry -L/Users/bertobettencourt/Desktop/LIVE\ RELEASES/Liga\ Zon\ Sagres\ (iOS)/1.30/Liga\ Zon\ Sagres\ Companion/Flurry\ iPhone\ SDK\ viPhone\ 4/Flurry-iOS-4.4.0/FlurryAds -F/Users/bertobettencourt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Liga_Zon_Sagres_Companion-fjlwctxjtriqrbgpjiscdoodhcgr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/bertobettencourt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Liga_Zon_Sagres_Companion-fjlwctxjtriqrbgpjiscdoodhcgr/Build/Intermediates/Liga\ Zon\ Sagres\ Companion.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Liga\ Zon\ Sagres\ Companion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Liga\ Zon\ Sagres\ Companion.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework AudioToolbox -framework MessageUI -lFlurry_4.4.0 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -framework CoreData -framework AdSupport -lFlurryAds_4.4.0 -lGoogleAdMobAds -framework iAd -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/bertobettencourt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Liga_Zon_Sagres_Companion-fjlwctxjtriqrbgpjiscdoodhcgr/Build/Intermediates/Liga\ Zon\ Sagres\ Companion.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Liga\ Zon\ Sagres\ Companion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Liga\ Zon\ Sagres\ Companion_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/bertobettencourt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Liga_Zon_Sagres_Companion-fjlwctxjtriqrbgpjiscdoodhcgr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Liga\ Zon\ Sagres\ Companion.app/Liga\ Zon\ Sagres\ Companion

ld: library not found for -lGoogleAdMobAds
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm new to iOS i do not know what is causing this, it seems i am missing the library, any idea where i can find it and how do i fix the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: **This was same problem for me , This soultion work perfectly in my case : Please try** : select your project > select project target >build phase >click on link Binary with libraries >click on + button and then click on Add other button and select GoogleMobileAds.framework , now clean your project , DONE, now build again. I hope it will help you. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can check my [so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800793/ld-library-not-found-for-lgoogleadmobads/22801813#22801813) here

Go to Project Navigator and find `libGoogleAdMobAds.a`. Just select it and on right side in `Target Membership` you would get your targets. Just deselect targets which are selected and again select them.

[image: For more help you can refer this image]

It may help you.

Comment: This works. But if i close Xcode and open again, it throws the same error. I need to redo the above steps again. Are there any fix for this problem?

Comment: In your build settings, find search path and check path of admob library. If there is any "space" in path then path will broke into number of lines when you reopen xcode. Just add " at start and end of path and make it of single line.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the library to your project by going to your project manager page (click the blue Xcode Project root ("iPhone Test" in this case) in the file browser tab on the left), and under General you should see the 'library' section. If you don't have the library (which I assume you do) it can be downloaded from Google's website.

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Comment: Hi, i have some libraries loaded, actually... a lot of them, one of them is libGoogleAdMobAds.a, so is it there, or is it missing?