# ld: library not found for -lGoogleAdMobAds

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, adsense

Trying to add **Google's MobAds** to my app.

I've followed every step but at the end I have a single fatal error.

Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKGCb.png).

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Go to Project Navigator and find `libGoogleAdMobAds.a`. Just select it and on right side in `Target Membership` you would get your targets. Just deselect targets which are selected and again select them.

[image]

It may help you.

Comment: You forgot to redact the name of your source code repository ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Check your library search path. Most of the time this error occurs because of this reason. You can find library search path under build setting.

**EDIT:**
[Thats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109085/adding-frameworks-to-project-in-xcode-5-and-having-relative-paths-added) a real good idea.

Comment: and what do i do there :P