# Library not found for -lpods - checking and rechecking target membership didn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

When I try and run my XCode project I get library not found for -lpods.  I've tried checking and unchecking the target membership as suggested at [ld: library not found for -lGoogleAdMobAds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800793/ld-library-not-found-for-lgoogleadmobads), but this hasn't made any difference.  I then tried the following:

```
Michaels-MacBook-Air:Chinese Restaurants michael$ open Chinese\ Restaurants.xcworkspace/
Michaels-MacBook-Air:Chinese Restaurants michael$ gem update system
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
Michaels-MacBook-Air:Chinese Restaurants michael$ gem update cocoapods
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
Michaels-MacBook-Air:Chinese Restaurants michael$ Pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (2.3.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Michaels-MacBook-Air:Chinese Restaurants michael$ open Chinese\ Restaurants.xcworkspace/
Michaels-MacBook-Air:Chinese Restaurants michael$ open Chinese\ Restaurants.xcworkspace/
Michaels-MacBook-Air:Chinese Restaurants michael$
```

Still no joy.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: are you sure you are opening/building the workspace (as opposed to the project)?

Comment: I've tried repeatedly opening it, and other steps:

Comment: When I go to Products - Scheme - Edit Schemes it tells me there are Pods missing for both Pods and Pods-AFNetworking.  As I'm new to XCode how do I sort this out please?