# very odd error - ld: library not found for -lGoogleAdMobAds

Tags: xcode, admob

I know this issue has been over here, but I tried most of the solutions and it's still not working.
after adding a banner with Admob ( google ads ) I have this odd error within my project . 
when I first open Xcode and running the project i'm getting this error :
ld: library not found for -lGoogleAdMobAds
clang: error:

so what I did is , removing the libGoogleAdMobAds.a and then add it again. 
after doing these actions the project successfully building up. 
but what's odd is, when I close the project and open it again i'm getting the same error, so I need to delete the file and add it again to make the project work.
how can I permanently get rid of this error  ? 
(BTW, I add -Objc to my project already)

Comment: Have you copied the lib into the project group/folder in xcode or are you just referring from another folder outside the project?

Comment: yup and I double checked, the files are in the project folder .

Comment: Pls check this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799186/admob-for-ios-error-llibrary-not-found-for-lgoogleadmobads     Hope this helps.